# How to create a ParamConverter<Integer> that handles primitive int as well?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

So I want to create a custom `ParamConverter<Integer>` in jax-rs:

```
public class IntParamConverter implements ParamConverter<Integer>{

    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String value) {
        try{
            return Integer.valueOf(value);
        }catch (Exception e){
            //do some stuff
            throw new BadRequestEx("Convert Exception");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(Integer value) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

And then I register it via ParamConverterProvider:

```
@Provider
public class CustomParamConverterHandler implements ParamConverterProvider {

        @Override
        public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(final Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
            if (rawType.equals(Integer.class)){
                return (ParamConverter<T>) new IntParamConverter();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And then use it in a Resource POJO as follows:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/conv")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String conv(@QueryParam("no") int no) {
        return ""+no;
    }
```

In runtime (testing with system.out) I find out that Tomee (Apache cfx?) does not use my `IntParamConverter`. If instead I declare `@QueryParam("no") Integer no` as opposed to `@QueryParam("no") int no`then everything works fine (tomee uses my custom paramConverter.

I tried registering my `IntParamConverter` with primitive int:

```
if (rawType.equals(int.class)){
     return (ParamConverter<T>) new IntParamConverter();
}
```

but then a runtime exception occures:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.handleParameter(InjectionUtils.java:388)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.createParameterObject(InjectionUtils.java:978)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readQueryString(JAXRSUtils.java:1210)
```

How can I create such a ParamConverter that handles primitive int?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Java generics are all converted to `java.lang.Object` on compilation (by a process called *type erasure*).

The primitive types such as `int` do not have `java.lang.Object` as their base class so such a conversion is not possible in such cases.

Comment: I get that, but how does Apache CFX or other implementations do this? If I do not register my custom IntParamConverter, Tomee does the work perfectly providing an int value. It's just that on invalid int input tomee returns Error 404, and I wanted to avoid that...

Answer (score 1):

I won't say definitively that it's a bug, but their implementation of `InjectionUtils.handleParameter` is weird. They have the following

```
// [...]
Object result = null;
try {
    result = createFromParameterHandler(value, pClass, genericType, paramAnns, message); 
} catch (IllegalArgumentException nfe) {
    throw createParamConversionException(pType, nfe);
}
```

to get the value form your `ParamConveter`. Then they do this

```
if (result != null) {
    return pClass.cast(result);
}
// [...]
```

Obviously, the `cast` will be attempted and fail. But there's no reason to cast like this for primitive types, reflection's `Method#invoke` will take care of that. In other words, you can (and you must) pass an `Integer` value to `Method#invoke` and the runtime will take care of converting it for you.

If they wanted to make additional validation, they could first check if the target type was a primitive type, and do the appropriate validation (check if your value is of the corresponding wrapper type). For other types, they can fallback to `cast` (since the method return type is the generic `T` bound to `pClass`) or use something like `isInstance`.

I won't open a ticket with the devs, but a library with such high usage should be able to do this.

---

> How can I create such a ParamConverter that handles primitive int?

You can't. `ParamConverter` is a generic class and primitives don't work with generics. However, the library should support doing the final `Integer` to `int` conversion for you, but it seems it doesn't.

Comment: Valid point. I also thought the same when I looked at that "weird" cast in their implementation. Thing is I deployed the app in Glassfish, and I got the same behavior... Maybe it's a design choice rather than a bug? I would really like to open a ticket but don't know how :(